# View of a view of a numpy array is a copy?

Tags: python, numpy

If you change a view of a numpy array, the original array is also altered. This is intended behaviour.

```
arr = np.array([1,2,3])
mask = np.array([True, False, False])
arr[mask] = 0
arr
# Out: array([0, 2, 3])
```

However, if I take a view of such a view, and change that, then the original array is *not* altered:

```
arr = np.array([1,2,3])
mask_1 = np.array([True, False, False])
mask_1_arr = arr[mask_1]  # Becomes: array([1])
mask_2 = np.array([True])
mask_1_arr[mask_2] = 0
arr
# Out: array([1, 2, 3])
```

This implies to me that, when you take a view of a view, you actually get back a copy. Is this correct? Why is this?

The same behaviour occurs if I use numpy arrays of numerical indices instead of a numpy array of boolean values. (E.g. `arr[np.array([0])][np.array([0])] = 0` doesn't change the first element of `arr` to 0.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Selection by [basic slicing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing-and-indexing) always returns a view.  Selection by [advanced
indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) always returns a copy.  [Selection by boolean mask](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing) is a form of advanced
indexing. (The other form of advanced indexing is [selection by integer array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing).)

However, **assignment** by advanced indexing affects the original array.

So

```
mask = np.array([True, False, False])
arr[mask] = 0
```

affects `arr` because it is an assignment. In contrast,

```
mask_1_arr = arr[mask_1]
```

is selection by boolean mask, so `mask_1_arr` is a copy of part of `arr`.
Once you have a copy, the jig is up. When Python executes

```
mask_2 = np.array([True])
mask_1_arr[mask_2] = 0
```

the assignment affects `mask_1_arr`, but since `mask_1_arr` is a copy,
it has no effect on `arr`.

---

```
|            | basic slicing    | advanced indexing |
|------------+------------------+-------------------|
| selection  | view             | copy              |
| assignment | affects original | affects original  |
```

---

Under the hood, `arr[mask] = something` causes Python to call
`arr.__setitem__(mask, something)`.  The `ndarray.__setitem__` method is
implemented to modify `arr`. After all, that is the natural thing one should expect
`__setitem__` to do.

In contrast, as an expression `arr[indexer]` causes Python to call
`arr.__getitem__(indexer)`.  When `indexer` is a slice, the regularity of the
elements allows NumPy to return a view (by modifying the strides and offset). When `indexer`
is an arbitrary boolean mask or arbitrary array of integers, there is in general
no regularity to the elements selected, so there is no way to return a
view. Hence a copy must be returned.

Comment: This all makes sense! I guess then that there's no easy way to do a one-liner like `arr[x][y] = 1`. Right now I'm doing this by assigning an intermediate value, e.g. `int = arr[x]`; `int[y] = 1`; `arr[x] = int`.

Comment: If `x` is a boolean mask, a one-line equivalent would be `np.put(arr, np.flatnonzero(x)[y], 1)`. `np.flatnonzero(x)` converts the boolean mask to a 1D integer array. You can then select some subset of those integers using `np.flatnonzero(x)[y]` where `y` could be a basic slice or advanced indexer.  Then `np.put(arr, np.flatnonzero(x)[y], 1)` works since it is roughly equivalent to `arr.flat[np.flatnonzero(x)[y]] = 1`.

Comment: If `arr` is 1-dimensional, `arr[np.flatnonzero(x)[y]] = 1` also works. The purpose of `np.put` above is to provide an answer that works even if `arr` is n-dimensional.