# Updating elements in multiply indexed np.array

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

I have a 2D numpy array and need to update a selection of elements via multiple layers of indexing. The obvious way to do this for me does not work since it seems numpy is only updating a copy of the array and not the array itself:

```py
import numpy as np

# Create an array and indices that should be updated
arr = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)
idx = np.array([[0,2], [1,1],[2,0]])
bool_idx = np.array([True, True, False])

# This line does not work as intended since the original array stays unchanged
arr[idx[:,0],idx[:,1]][bool_idx] = -1 * arr[idx[:,0],idx[:,1]][bool_idx]
```

This is the resulting output:

```
>>> arr
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])
```

However, I expected this output:

```
>>> arr
array([[0, 1, -2],
       [3, -4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to mask the indices with the given `mask` and then index into `arr` and assign new values. For indexing, we can use `tuple(masked_indices)` to index or use the two columns of the index-array for integer-indexing, thus giving us two methods.

Method #1 :

```
arr[tuple(idx[bool_idx].T)] *= -1
```

Method #2 :

```
idx_masked = idx[bool_idx]
arr[idx_masked[:,0],idx_masked[:,1]] *= -1
```

**Why didn't the original method work?**

On LHS you were doing `arr[idx[:,0],idx[:,1]][bool_idx]`, which is esssentially two steps : `arr[idx[:,0],idx[:,1]]`, which under the hoods calls `arr.__getitem__(indexer)`*. When indexer is a slice, the regularity of the elements allows NumPy to return a view (by modifying the strides and offset). When indexer is an arbitrary boolean mask or arbitrary array of integers, there is in general no regularity to the elements selected, so there is no way to return a view. Let's call `arr[idx[:,0],idx[:,1]]` as `arr2`.

In the next step, with the combined `arr[idx[:,0],idx[:,1]][bool_idx]`, i.e. `arr2[bool_idx]`, under the hoods it calls `arr2.__setitem__(mask)`, which is implemented to modify `arr2` and as such doesn't propagate back to `arr`.

*Inspiration from - https://stackoverflow.com/a/38768993/.

More info on [`__getitem__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__),[`__setitem__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setitem__).

**Why did the methods posted in this post work?**

Because both directly used the `indexer` on `arr` with `arr.__setitem__(indexer)` that modifies `arr`.

Comment: Indeed this solves the problem, thank you! Could you explain why my initial attempt did not work?

Comment: @smonsays Added few comments on it.

Comment: @Divakar: If that was indeed the reason why OP's solution didn't work, all of these working solutions should fail for the same reason. For example, in your Method # 2, what you're doing is indeed advanced indexing with two integer index arrays of shape `(3,)` and `(3,)`. I think the real reason why OP's solution didn't work is because the final step in OP's solution applies **boolean index**, and the result of boolean indexing is always a 1d array, according to the docs, with no reference back to original array. For OP, the bool indexing returned shape `(2,)`, on which the scalar mul was done.

Comment: @fountainhead Yeah, wasn't exactly correct. Edited the post.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to make a small change to your own attempt -- you need to apply the boolean index array on each of your integer index expressions. In other words, this should work:

```
arr[idx[:,0][bool_idx],idx[:,1][bool_idx]] *= -1
```

(I've just moved the `[bool_idx]` inside the square brackets, to apply it on the both of the integer index expressions -- `idx[:,0]` and `idx[:,1]`)